# Identifying string values or error sent from RServe in java

Tags: java, r, rserve

This is my sample R file :

```
# filename: sample.R
main <- function (){
  returnStringValue <- "ignore"
  return (returnStringValue)
}
main()
```

Now I am trying to source on the file on Rserve using java:

```
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXP;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;

public class RServeTest {

    static RConnection rcon;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String fileName = "sample.R";
            String filePath = "/filepath/";

            try {
                rcon = new RConnection();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error Connecting: "+e);
            }

            String rCode = "source(\""+filePath+fileName+"\")";
            System.out.println("Rscript call on file: "+rCode);


            REXP r = rcon.parseAndEval("try(eval(parse(text="+rCode+")),silent=TRUE)");

            System.out.println("r object: "+r.asString());

            if (r.inherits("try-error")) 
                System.err.println("Error: "+r.asString());
            else 
                System.out.println("Executed R code successfully.");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Rscript call on file: source("/home/maverick/Documents/sem3/agent code/sample.R")
Error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ignore' not found
```

How do I handle string values getting returned from the R code, without affecting the errors getting caught?

For eg:

Let's say I have a bug in my code:

```
main <- function (){
  returnStringValue <- "ignore"

  # error
  var1+1

  return (returnStringValue)
}
main()
```

The java code should log :

```
Rscript call on file: source("/filepath/sample.R")
Error: Error in main() : object 'var1' not found
```

rather than logging :

```
org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed, request status: error code: 127
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.eval(RConnection.java:233)
    at RServeTest.main(RServeTest.java:39)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error can be solved by returning a json object from R, instead of a string value. Here is how I solved this error:

Java code to source R file and run main() function:

```
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXP;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;

public class RServeTest {

    static RConnection rcon;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String fileName = "sample.R";
            // Note: Change filename for testing different samples

            String filePath = "/filepath/";

            try {
                rcon = new RConnection();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error Connecting: "+e);
            }

            String rCode = "source(\""+filePath+fileName+"\")";
            System.out.println("Rscript call on file: "+rCode);

            // Source file
            REXP r0 = rcon.parseAndEval("try(eval(parse(text="+rCode+")),silent=TRUE)");

            // Run main() function
            REXP r = rcon.parseAndEval("try(eval(parse(text=main())),silent=TRUE)");


            System.out.println("\n---------  with try error ------------");

            if (r.inherits("try-error")) 
                System.out.println("Error: "+r.asString());
            else 
                System.out.println("Executed R code successfully."+"r object: "+r.asString());

            System.out.println("\n---------  without try error ------------");

            System.out.println("R output :"+rcon.eval("main()").asString());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

R code Sample 1:

```
main <- function (){
  returnStringValue <- "ignore"
  return (returnStringValue)
}
```

Results:

```
Rscript call on file: source("/filepath/sample1.R")

---------  with try error ------------
Error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ignore' not found


---------  without try error ------------
R output :ignore
```

Without `try-error` method gives us the return string value we wanted, but if there is an error, as in the case below, it returns `eval failed` which can only be logged using the `try-error` method (please see sample 2).

---

R code Sample 2:

```
main <- function (){

  # error
  var1+1

  returnStringValue <- "ignore"
  return (returnStringValue)
}
```

Results:

```
Rscript call on file: source("/filepath/sample2.R")

---------  with try error ------------
Error: Error in main() : object 'var1' not found


---------  without try error ------------
org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed, request status: error code: 127
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.eval(RConnection.java:233)
    at RServeTest.main(RServeTest.java:43)
```

---

The aforementioned issue can be dealt with, by returning a json object from R instead of a string value. Here are sample codes and results:

R code Sample 3:

```
require('rjson')
main <- function (){

  # error
  var1+1

  returnStringValue <- "ignore"
  returnJsonObject <- toJSON(returnStringValue)
  return (returnJsonObject)
}
```

Results:

```
Rscript call on file: source("/filepath/sample3.R")

---------  with try error ------------
Error: Error in main() : object 'var1' not found


---------  without try error ------------
org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed, request status: error code: 127
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.eval(RConnection.java:233)
    at RServeTest.main(RServeTest.java:43)
```

---

R code Sample 4:

```
require('rjson')
main <- function (){

  returnStringValue <- "ignore"
  returnJsonObject <- toJSON(returnStringValue)

  return (returnJsonObject)
}
```

Results:

```
Rscript call on file: source("/filepath/sample4.R")

---------  with try error ------------
Executed R code successfully.r object: ignore

---------  without try error ------------
R output :"ignore"
```

Hence, from sample 3 and 4 you can see that we have achieved our desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure about this, although I can't run and verify what the accuracy of that written below:

The problem is in storing `rCode` in the variable `text` which makes `REXP r` to become an assignment instead of just returning a string. Try removing `text=` and your code should work fine.

Update with further developments if the above worked.

Comment: I don't think that's an issue. When I do that I get this error
`Error: Error in file(filename, "r") : cannot open the connection`